# Do we have Interceptors for JSON actions in Struts2

Tags: java, json, struts2

In my application I have configured Session interceptor for the actions in Default package (i.e. actions with result type JSP or tiles).  Is there any option to configure Interceptor for actions in JSON package.  i.e. Action classes with JSON results.

Here is my Struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="sessionInterceptor" class="com.dar.session.SessionInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-stack name="myInterceptorStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
                <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor"/>
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <action name="createCampaign">
            <interceptor-ref name="myInterceptorStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result type="tiles">createCampaign</result>
        </action>
    </package>
    <package name="example" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult"/>
        </result-types>
       <action name="peopleCountAction" class="com.dar.business.BusinessSearchAction" method="findPeopleCount">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="includeProperties">peopleCount</param>
            </result>
       </action> 
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by interceptor for package as packages are only logical separation and interceptors are fired per request basis

Comment: @Umesh:  In struts.xml we have <package name="default"> tag.  Actions which are declared under <package name="***" extends="json-default">.  Is we can have interceptor for this actions.

Comment: You mean all the action defined under the package `default`?

Comment: Do you mean changing the interceptorStack package to package?

Comment: @Umesh:  I have two packages in struts.xml 1.  is <package extends="struts-default"><action/>... </package> 2.  <package extends ="json-default"></package>.   I successfully configured Session Interceptor for Package-I(i.e. struts-default).   But I want to configure above or any other interceptor for Package-2 (i.e JSON-default).   IS it possible?

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV :  I didn't configured the Interceptor Stack for all the packages Is it possible to configure the same Interceptor stack for all package.

Comment: @Arun i believe you  can create our own named stacks and even declare a new default interceptor stack for a package, else better show the part where you configured one interceptor for the first package to get some idea what exactly you trying to do

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi : Here is my Code    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
     <result-types>
   <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
  </result-types>
        <interceptors>
   <interceptor name="sessionInterceptor" class="com.dsr.session.SessionInterceptor" />
   <interceptor-stack name="myInterceptorStack">
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
       <interceptor-ref name="sessionInterceptor"/>
      </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptors>
</package>

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi:  ANd JSON Package <package name="example" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
<result-types>
         <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult"/>
     </result-types>
     <action name="offersGrid" class="com.dsr.business.offer.BusinessOffersGridAction">
   <result type="json" name="success"></result>
  </action>
</package>

Comment: @Arun Add info to the question, not as comments--it's illegible. I'm still not sure what your question is: you can define interceptor stacks for any package or action, it doesn't matter what package it extends.

Comment: @DaveNewton :  I have updated the question.  Can u please look into my struts.xml,  I have defined interceptor stack for only one package.  Is it possible to configure common Interceptor stack both packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<struts>
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="SecurityInterceptor"
            class="com.i2c.cportal.framework.interceptors.SecurityInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor name="cacheInterceptor"
            class="com.i2c.cportal.framework.interceptors.CachingInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="jsonStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="SecurityInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="cacheInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="jsonStack"></default-interceptor-ref>
    <default-action-ref name="defaultAction"></default-action-ref>
    <action method="getJsonOfOrders" name="getJsonOfOrders" class="sample.SampleAction">
        <result type="json" />
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

It will work you just have to define stack and use and remember to use default stack else SessionAware session will become null if you are using it.